# merge multiple zip files in python

Tags: python-3.x, file, merge, zip

I know there are a couple of similar questions, from which i actually took bits of this code, but I cannot understand why I get the error i get.

I have 3 urls which get me a zip file each, I would like to merge them into 1 using python without saving to disc.

```
import zipfile
import io
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError


EA = 'https://fews.net/data_portal_download/download?data_file_path=http%3A//' \
     'shapefiles.fews.net.s3.amazonaws.com/HFIC/EA/east-africa202006.zip'
SA = 'https://fews.net/data_portal_download/download?data_file_path=http%3A//' \
     'shapefiles.fews.net.s3.amazonaws.com/HFIC/SA/southern-africa202006.zip'
WA = 'https://fews.net/data_portal_download/download?data_file_path=http%3A//' \
     'shapefiles.fews.net.s3.amazonaws.com/HFIC/WA/west-africa202006.zip'

urls = [EA, SA, WA]

# supporting funcs

def get_zip(url):                                                      
                                                                       
    try:                                                               
        response = requests.get(url)                                   
                                                                       
        # If the response was successful, no Exception will be raised  
        response.raise_for_status()                                    
                                                                       
    except HTTPError as http_err:                                      
        print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')                      
                                                                       
    except Exception as err:                                           
        print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')                          
                                                                       
    else:                                                              
        return response                                                


def merge_zip_files(zipfiles):                                         
                                                                       
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipfiles[0], 'a') as first_zipfile:           
        for filename in zipfiles[1:]:                                  
            other_zipfile = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'r')             
            for n in other_zipfile.namelist():                         
                first_zipfile.writestr(n, other_zipfile.open(n).read())
                                                                       
    return first_zipfile  

# extract and merge zip files

zipfiles = [get_zip(url).content for url in urls]
filebytes = [io.BytesIO(zfile) for zfile in zipfiles]
zipfiles_objects = [zipfile.ZipFile(fbytes) for fbytes in filebytes]

# til here no error

merged_zipfile = merge_zip_files(zipfiles=zipfiles)
```

At this point i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 1287, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 1330, in _RealGetContents
    endrec = _EndRecData(fp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 262, in _EndRecData
    fpin.seek(0, 2)
AttributeError: 'ZipFile' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I spotted the error -

I had no need of line

```
zipfiles_objects = [zipfile.ZipFile(fbytes) for fbytes in filebytes]
```

Without this line the `merge_zip_files()` function now gets a list of files in bytes ready to be passed to `zipfile.ZipFile()` method, which I was doing twice with that line I pasted here above.

SFS everyone.